# DataBinding in ControlTemplate to DependencyProperty works, but still throws errors

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a custom Button with an Angle DependencyProperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Angle",
        typeof(float),
        typeof(TriangularButton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0f, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public float Angle
{
    get { return (float)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
}
```

In the ControlTemplate I want to bind to Angle. I tried several ways (see below) and each one works, but I get a System.Windows.Data Error. How do I get rid of it?

What I tried:

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Path ...>
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

Then I get:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Angle; DataItem=null; target element is 'RotateTransform' (HashCode=55197304); target property is 'Angle' (type 'Double')

When I do this:

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Path ...>
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

Then I get:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Button', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Angle; DataItem=null; target element is 'RotateTransform' (HashCode=24935945); target property is 'Angle' (type 'Double')

**EDIT:**

Thank to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6582090/2102827) I found out the cause is probably because the Button is not initially visible. If I put the Button somewhere where it's initially visible, the error goes away. Is there a way to get rid of the error when I am using the Button somewhere that's not initially visible?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify the source if you specify DataContext on your button

EDIT:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="1"/>
        <TabItem Header="2">
            <Grid>
                <local:TriangularButton Angle="45" Width="100" Height="100">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Path Stroke="Red" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100"/>
                                </Path.Data>
                                <Path.RenderTransform >
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                            </Path>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </local:TriangularButton>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

DP

```
rusing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Test
{
    public class TriangularButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Angle",
        typeof(float),
        typeof(TriangularButton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0f, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public float Angle
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

}
 code here

And it works great, even i open from another tab.

[image: First tab opened]

[image: Tab with button]

You may add RenderTransformOrigin at your Path.

Comment: The DataContext ist the Button itself. The DependencyProperty is in the code behind.

Comment: @gartenriese give me a second

Comment: I may have found the cause for the error, see the edit. However I still don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>

Comment: But it works for me, do you want to rotate button? As i understood

Comment: See my earlier edit. The cause is probably because it's not initially visible. Try putting the Button in a TabControl where a different tab is initially selected and you will (probably) get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120487/discussion-between-denis-kosov-and-gartenriese).

Comment: And you don't get any errors? My Button rotates just fine too, it's just annoying to see the error in the output.